# Canvas element lines aren't straight?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to draw an element on a canvas but whenever I draw the canvas, the lines turn out faded and not bold. I don't understand why this happening with my code.. whenever I try it with code from W3schools it turns out fine. Here is my code and an image below.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Talk Walk</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #canvas {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      height: 500px;
      width: 750px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that there's some aliasing going on when you're drawing the rectangles.
This is happening because the "edge" of the green rectangle isn't drawn exactly on a pixel. Normally, you wouldn't really see it, but since you're stretching out the canvas by using css to set it's width and height, you get this result:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

```css
#canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 750px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

To fix that, use the `width` and `height` HTML attributes, instead of css:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

```css
#canvas {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="750"></canvas>
```

This properly scales the canvas, so the aliasing (while still there if you zoom in) doesn't scale up.